# serial port communication in linux OS

Tags: java, linux

Can anyone tell me whats the best and efficient way to communicate to a serial port connected devices in linux operating system.I am trying to send messages to eftpos machine using serial port in my java program. Any suggestion and advice would be great !!! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638553/how-do-i-get-java-to-use-the-serial-port-in-linux) points out the [serialio](http://serialio.com/products/serialport/serialport.php) driver as an option. You might also have a look at [javacomm](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html) from sun/oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Open the appropriate device file. Eg, /dev/cu.foo

Comment: `/dev/ttyS0` (…ttyS1, ttyS2…) on every system I've seen. `/dev/cu` is ooooold.

Comment: @duskwuff: So it is.  Mac OS X still has them.